# How to make IIS7 stop serving a folder?

Tags: iis-7

I know that by defualt IIS won't server App_Data or bin folders content to the public.
How to set one more folder to don't server to public?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The proper way to do that is using this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
               <hiddenSegments>
                   <add segment="My_Directory" />
               </hiddenSegments>
           </requestFiltering>
       </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This allows you to still access files located there from the `IUSR` account, but prevents actual requests for files there from being filled directly.

Note that this will block files in that directory, and any subdirectories, no matter where that directory occurs - even if it, itself, is a sub-directory of something else.

Comment: The above code should be placed in a web.config file in the same directory as the directory you want to deny access from.  I tested putting it in my root level web.config, and it blocked access to the entire site.  Putting it in a separate web.config file in the same directory returns a 404 error when attempting to access the directory (though I'm sure the type of error it returns can be changed in IIS).

Comment: Mostly obvious, but..   "My_Directory" is not literal and should be the name of your directory!

Answer (score 3):

As the link-only answer points out, `hiddenSegments` is the right tool for the job. Go to `IIS` then the `site` and in `Features` find `Request Filtering` (must be installed at `Server Manager`) now add directory name that you want to prevent access to, or any segment of the URL really. This approach does require that a unique url or directory name be used in the site, otherwise any other occurrence of the segment at any level in the url, will cause that request to be blocked:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments

Answer (score 1):

Remove IIS_IUSR permissions from that folder.

I think its generically under the "Internet Guest Account"

Comment: If you do that, you may also be blocking any ability to access those files via the web application at all, which is probably not what is intended.

Comment: I Removing the IIS_IUSR will work in my case, I want to save there users uploads, now I am saving them on somewhere out side the website folder on the c: drive, and this uploads folder does not have IIS_IUSR permission and I still can access it from my website code.