# How do i make folder on server secure?

Tags: php, security, directory, hitcounter

I'm creating a website on my local computer and have no database system.

For each user entering the page, i create a text file with their IP adress as the name.
So when i go on the website when it's hosted on my computer, a PHP script creates a file hits/127.0.0.1.txt.

The file contains some sensitive information, and i dont want anything else then my PHP scripts to access the files.

When i write 'localhost/mysite/hits/' i can access all the text files and information.
I'd like to prevent this so people wont be able to see this when i publish the site

How can i do this?

And by the way, I create this file to use it to count visitors and see when i get most visitors.

Comment: Code you have tried? Share you will?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Bad way. Why you do not use Analytics or one of log analyzers?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've not tried anything yet, Just thinking for about 30 minutes.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I'm already finished with the hitcounter, i just need to know how to prevent people from accessing the files.

Comment: Look about the .htaccess file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is depending on your Webserver

**Apache:**

You need to insert in the directory a `.htaccess` file, with content `deny from all`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9282193/2441442

**IIS:**

You need a File `web.config` to configure Request Filtering:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <security>
          <requestFiltering>
               <hiddenSegments>
                   <add segment="My_Directory" />
               </hiddenSegments>
           </requestFiltering>
       </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038572/2441442

**Nginx:**

You write in your Configuration:

```
location ~ /(dir1|dir2|dir3) {
   deny all;
   return 404;
}
```

Because of the background of Nginx (Performance) you need to restart the server. The config is only one time loaded.

https://serverfault.com/a/232706/220399

**For all other**

http://bit.ly/1ktwZHG

Comment: @JayBlanchard i have improved my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Worked out great :)
Will accept your awnser as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and create an .htaccess file in the folder and deny all in the .htaccess script