# How to limit access to a website directory via url

Tags: php, web-hosting, iis-8

I have a `website` made in `php` and hosted from scratch using `IIS`. Below is the `directory structure`.

```
--> WebSite
    |-> Folder1
    |-> Folder2
    |-> Folder3
    |-> index.php
```

When a user types in the browser `http://website/folder1/*` he can access all the content inside the `Folder1` folder. I want to deny access to that folder for example.

So far I have tried two solutions.
The first solution was to restructure the `director`y as follows, but it didn't work for me.

```
--> WebSite
    |-> Deny
        |-> Folder1
    |-> Allow
        |-> Folder2
        |-> Folder3
        |-> index.php
```

The second was adding a `filtering rule` in the `request filtering / url` section, but as soon as the `web.config` file is created, it gives me the following error when I try to browse the site.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Error Code     0x80070005
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File    *\web.config
```

What should I do?

Comment: 1) PHP 8 (and above) is not supported by Microsoft on IIS, https://news-web.php.net/php.internals/110907. 2) IIS was not designed to support non .NET web stacks with integrated authorization support, so you shouldn't waste too much time on that direction. Start from a Linux machine and things should be fine.

Comment: I am not sure if your filtering rule in Web.Config file has any issue. You could refer to the example mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038572/10309381). You could try to modify the Web.Config file to add the filtering rule. See whether it works.